# Supported docker packages - docker.io

Tags: docker, support

Is there an official docker package supported by Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, docker.io?  Should I go to Docker for the ee version?

Thanks,

Comment: You can install the official docker packages using the `apt` using the command `sudo apt install docker.io`

Comment: Historically, most packages have not been "official," and "supported" could have several meanings. Distributed software is usually packaged, and bugs triaged and forwarded, by volunteers. That's how Debian and Debian-based distros (like Ubuntu) have worked for 30 years. If you are using "officially supported" as shorthand for something (like "tested", "compatible", "receives updates", or something else) best to be specific about what you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

"*Is there an official docker package supported by Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, docker.io?*"

Let's find out...

```
$ apt-cache madison docker.io
 docker.io | 20.10.21-0ubuntu1~22.04.5 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
```

...so the package is in Universe.

Next, let's see what being in Universe means ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#The_Four_Main_Repositories)):

> Universe - Community-maintained free and open-source software.

It does NOT say "Canonical-supported" or "officially supported".

---

"*Should I go to Docker for the ee version?*"

That's up to you.
Do your research, make your decision.

Comment: Note that "Officially supported version" is subjective.  Because Docker is in Universe, it isn't necessarily "officially supported".  Docker has their own repositories that they actually recommend be used instead of the version in Ubuntu, because the version in Ubuntu may not actually be fully supported by Docker upstream and such.  Just my two cents/recommendation that you keep in mind Universe isn't "supported" necessarily.

Comment: @ThomasWard edited to address. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not maintain the packages you find in apt. They are unofficial images managed by the community.

You can find this information in their installation documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

> Distro maintainers provide unofficial distributions of Docker packages in APT. You must uninstall these packages before you can install the official version of Docker Engine.

As for installing Docker, if you don't want to use the community-provided package, the officially recommended way to install Docker is by adding the [docker official repository](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu).

An extended guide can be found on the same documentation link I [shared above](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/), which mentions 22.04 as a supported version.

Regarding the "ee" version, if you meant the docker enterprise edition, then that no longer exists, as another company has bought it off.